# ADSL link is dropping regularly around 9am in the morning

Tags: networking, router, adsl2+

We have a Telstra link which is connecting to a SRX at-1/0/0 interface.
Link is having dropouts every day around 9 in the morning.
Checked with Telstra already and they don't observe any issues with the link

Last flapped   : 2017-08-08 8:58:41 EST

Can see that CRC errors are increasing also( Already changed the cable )

```
                             Interleave       Fast  Interleave       Fast
Bit rate (kbps)   :                14891          0         940          0
CRC               :                    0       1634           0          0
FEC               :                    0          0           0          0
HEC               :                58996          0        1232          0


Vendor Specific:                     0x9385                 0xa3f5
```

ADSL Statistics:                        ATU-R                  ATU-C
    Attenuation (dB)         :             31.5                   19.5
    Capacity used (%)        :                0                      0
    Noise margin (dB)        :              6.0                    4.5
    Output power (dBm)       :             18.5                   12.0

Discards are visible from monitoring

[image]

Any advice would be really appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Has Telstra tech support tried monitoring the link _at 9 am_?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some heavy machine nearby ramping up at that time? Have seen a similar effect with a tomography machine used for research. Do you know if that happens on weekend days, too?